# Subscription in Math

Tags: notation

In this document:

[image]

What do the expressions like

$$\ (n+v)_n $$ $$\ (m-v)_k $$ $$\ (n-v)_m $$

mean?

Comment: Thanks for the enlargement, @Bye_World!

Comment: It seems [Pochhammer symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). Reading a bit [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-216/S0025-5718-96-00774-0/S0025-5718-96-00774-0.pdf) text about the same topic seems it. In this context the Pochhammer symbol is a rising factorial generally.

Comment: Yes, after a little research , I found it as pochhammer symbols ,too. Thanks for your help.